# Getting modification date-time of a file with seconds in cmd.exe

Tags: windows, file, cmd

I've created a batch which automatically uploads some files to FTP server, if they're modified. And modification is detected by changed file's modification time and size.
But if the modification is made within the same minute, and file size did not change, modification stays undetected, and file is not uploaded. 
Is there a way to get exact modification time (including seconds) of a file in a windows batch?

Comment: I wonder why you are writing batch file to sync files when this has been done various ways.  I like Unison myself, but maybe it doesn't support FTP (http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).  I would think there must be something out there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of VBScript that might do it for you:

```
set FSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

if WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 then
    Wscript.Echo "No files specified"
    Wscript.Quit 1
end if

Set File=FSO.GetFile( WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
Date2=File.DateLastModified 
Wscript.Echo date2
```

Comment: I personally prefer JavaScript, but this is a great clue, since looks like there's no other solution.

Comment: Yeah VBScript is awful, and it's verry strange that there is no way to get timestamp with seconds precision using default tools.